# Get the position of first not 0 decimal digit

Tags: javascript, numbers, decimal

I need to find the position of the first not "0" decimal digit. For instance

```
a = 0.00056;
```

the fist not "0" digit after the dot is 5, and the searched position is 4. Is there a javascript function already built or an elegant way to get it in javascript?

Just for curiosity, I then will keep 0.00001 as stepping value in a slider the maximum value of which is the variable a.

Comment: Convert it to an array of characters, then use the `Array.prototype.findIndex()` method.

Comment: Another method is to keep multiplying by 10 until it's >= 1. The number of iterations is your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could take the logarithm of ten and take a floored value.

```js
var a = 0.00056,
    p = Math.floor(Math.log10(a));

console.log(p);
```

Comment: Nice, you just need to negate it to get a positive number.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with string manipulation, or with pure numbers.

The mathematical way is:

> ```
> Math.floor(Math.abs(Math.log10(n))); // if n >= 0 && n < 1
> ```

```js
let arr = [
  0.56,    // 0
  0.056,   // 1
  0.0056,  // 2
  0.00056, // 3
  0.000056 // 4
];

arr.forEach(a => {
  console.log(`n = ${a}, str = ${getFirstNonZeroStr(a)}, log = ${getFirstNonZeroLog(a)}`);
});

function getFirstNonZeroStr(n) {
  if (n >= 1) return -1;
  let s = n.toString();
  let m = s.match(/^0\.(0*)[\d]+$/);
  return m[1].length;
}

function getFirstNonZeroLog(n) {
  if (n >= 1) return -1;
  return Math.floor(Math.abs(Math.log10(n)));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just adding another way by converting it to a string and using a reg exp

```js
a = 0.00056;
console.log(a.toString().match(/0\.(0*[^0])/)[1].length)
```